# Is there a python code for finding the combination of a row with only some colums are variable

Tags: python

I have a row of string data like:

```
A, B, C/D , E/F, J , K
```

I want to find the non repeating combination of whole row where only column data containing "/" undergo combination (python code 3.x )

Output:

```
A,B,C,E,J,K
A,B,D,E,J,K
A,B,C,F,J,K
A,B,D,F,J,K
```

Single Items are constant columns. It is preferable if the code works with N number of columns and m number of items within each variable colums. Please help

I could not use any of python builtin methods directly to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
from itertools import product
s = ['A', 'B', 'C/D', 'E/F', 'J', 'K']
s = [x.split('/') for x in s]
for p in product(*s):
    print(''.join(p))
```

Output

```
ABCEJK
ABCFJK
ABDEJK
ABDFJK
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to compute the answer recursively:

```
def _compute_result(arr, i, prefix, results):
    if i == len(arr):
        results.append(','.join(prefix))
        return
    for j in arr[i].split('/'):
        _compute_result(arr, i + 1, prefix + [j], results)


string_array = input().strip().split(' ')
results = []
_compute_result(string_array, 0, [], results)
print(' '.join(results))
```

O/P:

```
A,B,C,E,J,K A,B,C,F,J,K A,B,D,E,J,K A,B,D,F,J,K
```